# Bind Command for MenuItem in DataTemplate without Tag

Tags: wpf, command, datatemplate

I want to bind a command in my ViewModel to a menuItem which is in DataTemplate. I can do that with using Tag. Is there any method which can do the same task but without using tag.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StudentListBoxItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Trigger" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.TriggerCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}" 
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudentListBoxItemTemplate}">
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

My ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel {
    public ICommand TriggerCommand { ... }
    public ObservableList<Student> StudentList { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current design, you need to get from the `ContextMenu` through the `StackPanel` and back to the `DataContext` of the containing `ListBox`.  What makes this awkward is that the `DataContext` of the `StackPanel` is already narrowed down to a particular student.

There are at least two ways to make this easier:

- Provide a `TriggerCommand` property in `Student` so the command is right there where you need it
- Provide a `Parent` property in the `Student` to escape the narrowed scope

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add click event to the menuItem like following

```
<Menu Style="{StaticResource bellRingersFontStyle}" Height="23" Name="menu1" Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_New Member" Name="newMember" Click="newMember_Click" >
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Face.bmp" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save Member Details" Name="saveMember" IsEnabled="False" Click="saveMember_Click">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Note.bmp" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="E_xit" Name="exit" Click="exit_Click"  />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                <MenuItem Header="_About Middleshire Bell Ringers" Name="about" Click="about_Click" >
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Ring.bmp" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

**Try binding the command to Click**. My VS is down so can't check at this moment.

Comment: I want to put the logic on the ViewModel instead of the code behind. So I use Command instead of Click.

Comment: Why don't you try including the ViewModel in Window.Resources and then try Binding the Command to MenuItem. BTW i am not too sure. But seems logical to me as of now

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to get the context menu collection presentation defined in your viewmodel, which will contain the header string and command action (maybe with predicate).

The viewmodel creates an observable collection of the contextmenu items and the view binds that to ContextMenu itemssource and sets the displaymember path to header string.